# Qt5 - why not screenshot and saving to a file?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, qpixmap

Why its not saving any file?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QList>
#include <QScreen>


QPixmap grabScreens() {
  auto screens = QGuiApplication::screens();
  QList<QPixmap> scrs;
  int w = 0, h = 0, p = 0;
  foreach (auto scr, screens) {
    QPixmap pix = scr->grabWindow(0);
    w += pix.width();
    if (h < pix.height()) h = pix.height();
    scrs << pix;
  }
  QPixmap final(w, h);
  QPainter painter(&final);
  final.fill(Qt::black);
  foreach (auto scr, scrs) {
    painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(p, 0), scr);
    p += scr.width();
  }
  return final;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPixmap pixmap = grabScreens();

    QFile file("file.jpg");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    pixmap.save(&file, "JPG", 1);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: To distinguish between a problem with your code and a problem with working directory configuration, try to hardcode the absolute output path.

Comment: Because C:\ likely requires administrator privileges to write to. Try a path within your home directory, e.g. Desktop

Comment: Its working now by adding C:\\

Comment: Yes, you should escape forward slashes. You can setup working directory (a directory where IDE runs your program) in project settings. In order to run the program without IDE, you need to include Qt's bin/ directory into your PATH environment variable or to copy required .dll files from there into program's directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you're looking for should be in the same folder of the executable.

If you're running your code from Qtcreator, it should be in the build directory, as specified in the Build Settings of the Projects page.

Comment: Please see my above EDIT screenshot. Its not saving there at all.

Comment: Try executing (double-click) untitled.exe directly and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) to query for a writable location for the screenshot to be saved to. This will avoid the issue of trying to write to a read-only directory.